# Apache Rewrite does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I wan't to force non-www but it does not working, here is my .conf from sites-available.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
DocumentRoot /var/www/example
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
<Directory "/var/www/example">
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</Directory>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
```

In case there is a conflict between my vhost conf and .htacess, ill show you my htaccess code also:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Uncomment the following line if server allows
    # This will compress js/css/html/php and increase site performance
    #<filesMatch "\.(js|css|html|php)$">
    #   SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    #</filesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this inside a `VirtualHost` directive tag? I don't see it. However the rule itself seems fine. Also don't forget to restart apache if you just added this.

Comment: Yes, i missed this line while cp. I've restarted the apache, i also deleted my browsers cache and cookies. Still does not work :(

Comment: "It's not working" is not a problem statement. If no problem statement is given, I must assume that purple unicorns pop up whenever you turn on your computer, which is expected behaviour. If this is not the case, **add the error message you get**. Give us as much information as possible. Urls. Http status codes. Anything else you might or might not observe.

Comment: Why are you using both? You should either put all .htaccess code in the config or all in .htaccess. It's recommended to use the config for all of it and set AllowOverride to `None` for better performance. .htaccess is mainly for shared hosting when you don't have access to the config.

Comment: @PanamaJack Thanks for the info and solution! I removed htaccess and used the config with AllowOverride to None. Now force non-www works :). You can post that as an answer so i can give you the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using both? You should either put all .`htaccess` code in the config or all in .htaccess. It's recommended to use the config for all of it and set `AllowOverride` to `None` for better performance. .`htaccess` is mainly for shared hosting when you don't have access to the config.